# nesting while loops, looping through one while loop repeatedly until the other loop has completed

Tags: python

I'm trying to use 2 while loops to return values `i` and `j`.

The below:

```
i=0
j=0
while i < 50:
    while j < 5:
        print('i: ' + str(i))
        print('j: ' + str(j))
        j += 1
    i += 10
```

results in:

```
i: 0
j: 0
i: 0
j: 1
i: 0
j: 2
i: 0
j: 3
i: 0
j: 4
```

However I'm trying to get:

```
i: 0
j: 0
i: 0
j: 1
i: 0
j: 2
i: 0
j: 3
i: 0
j: 4

i: 10
j: 1
i: 10
j: 2
i: 10
j: 3
i: 10
j: 4

i: 20
j: 1
i: 20
j: 2
i: 20
j: 3
i: 20
j: 4

etc...
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please give the full output of the first example. There is no possible way that it ends with `i` printed as `0`.

Comment: Where in your code do you see `j` being reset to `0`, or decreased in any way?  You initialize it to `0` once, outside of both loops.  After that it only changes from inside the inner loop.  So once the inner loop completes the first time, it will never run again.  You really should learn to debug this sort of thing.

Comment: Cory shows how to fix your problem. I also suggest you learn about the `range()` function. You can use it with a `for` loop to get the output you want instead of a `while` loop.

Comment: Also, [this article[(https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great tips for debugging your code.

Answer (score 2):

You should reinitialize `j` before entering the inner while loop

```
i = 0
while i < 50:
    j = 0
    while j < 5:
        print('i: ' + str(i))
        print('j: ' + str(j))
        j += 1
    i += 10
```

as an aside instead of nested loops I would instead use `itertools.product` here

```
from itertools import product
for i, j in product(range(0,50,10), range(5)):
    print(f'i: {i}')
    print(f'j: {j}')
```

Answer (score 1):

it is doing everything you want it to it just can't print it because j = 5 so the nested while loop is already false just move the declaration for j into the while loop

```
i=10
while i < 50:
    j=0
    while j < 5:
        print('i: ' + str(i))
        print('j: ' + str(j))
        j += 1
        continue
    i += 10
```

Answer (score -1):

After `i+=10`, do `j=0`.
Also you can print vars using `print(f'{i=}')`.